# C++ getline() jumped over empty strings

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

I'm reading with my c++ program csv file:

```
abc;def;ghi

10;;10
```

by this code:

```
    while(getline(in, str, '\n')){
      stringstream ss;
      while(getline(ss, str, ';')){
         line.add(str);
      }
    }
```

Where in is input file, `str` is string variable and line is my collection (like `vector`). But `getline` jumped over the empty string in csv file.

Can anyone help me to reading empty string, too?

Thanks :)

Comment: How do you know that it jumped? Anyway it will not enter second loop when the line is empty.

Comment: aram90: i have temp variable that counts numbers of reading and also in my list there is only 2 strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've never initialized your stream!

Try this:

```
#include <string>   // for std::string and std::getline
#include <sstream>  // for std::istringstream

for (std::string jimbob; std::getline(in, jimbob); )
{
    std::istringstream marysue(jimbob);  // !
    for (std::string charlie; std::getline(marysue, charlie, ';'); )
    {
        line.add(charlie);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've initialized it before by this:

    ifstream in ( inFileName );
    if (in.fail()) return false;

It's ok.

But compiler doesnt like your code :(

error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(std::ifstream)'

Comment: You seem to be doing something completely different. There is no `ifstream` in my code at all. Are you misspelling `ln` as `in`? Let me rename the variables.

Comment: @LukasHamrla: I find that hard to believe. The code does [exactly what it should](http://ideone.com/k5JMCr).